# Create equidistant points around a circle, based on Euclidean distance: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, geometry

I want N points on a circle, set apart by a Euclidean distance (straight line, not around the circumference) of 50. The radius is determined by the number of points and the distance between consecutive points.

However, when I choose one of the points as a reference and calculate the distances to other points, I do not get any distance values equal to 50.

Below is my code:

```
N        =  100;    % number of points
eclddst  =  50;     % euclidean distance between adjacent points
r        =  eclddst/(2*sin(pi/N));         % radius of the circle 
cord     =  r*exp((0:1/(N-1):1)*pi*2*1i)'; % coordinates
XCor     =  real(cord);
YCor     =  imag(cord);
N_COORD  =  [XCor YCor];
% taking location 3 as the reference point to check the distance between the points
DSTNT    =  sqrt( (N_COORD(3,1)-N_COORD(:,1)).^2 + ( N_COORD(3,2)- N_COORD(:,2)).^2)';
```

The distance values around the third point which I obtain are:

```
100.959
 50.505
  0.000
 50.505
100.959
151.311
```

The points adjacent to point 3 should have `50` as their distance value and not  `50.505`.

Why do I get this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the formula for cord coming from? And why do you use imaginary stuff? Also, just an off-topic tip: use `linspace(0,1,N)` instead of `0:1/(N-1):1`

Comment: @Tina The formula of cord was obtained  from this  [link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/315743).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in the number of points which your formula generates, because of a misleading statement at the [link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/315743) you were following. Note that it was stated:

```
r = A*exp((0:1/300:1)*pi*2j); % 300 point circle, radius A
```

However, this will give 301 points not 300. If you plotted this though, you would see only 300 points (much easier to see if you use, say, 4 points). The first and last points are identical since

```
exp(0*pi*2j) = exp(1*pi*2j) = 1
```

To get around this, the simplest options are to change `0:1/300:1` to not reach 1, or simply create and remove an extra point as shown here:

```
N =  100;    % number of points
d =  50;     % Euclidean distance between adjacent points
% Euclidean distance around circle is essentially side length of N-sided polygon.
% Triangular sector angle within polygon (rads): 2*pi/N 
% By bisecting the triangle to get a right-triangle, we can deduce that
% sin((2*pi/N)/2) = (d/2)/r  =>  r = (d/2)/sin(pi/N)
r = (d/2)/sin(pi/N);
% Use linspace as it's clearer than colon array, create N+1 points
% Note that point 1 and point N+1 will be identical!
complexcoords =  r*exp(linspace(0,1,N+1)*pi*2*1i).'; 
% Remove the last point as you put it in an array
coords        =  [real(complexcoords(1:N)) imag(complexcoords(1:N))];
```

As a check:

```
% Euclidean distances from point 3
dists = sqrt((coords(3,1)-coords(:,1)).^2 + (coords(3,2)-coords(:,2)).^2);
dists(1:5)
>> 99.951
       50  % Neighbouring points are distance 50! 
        0
       50  % Ditto
   99.951
```

---

Note that you should be careful using `'`. This is the complex conjugate transpose, meaning that `x + yi` becomes `x - yi`. You won't notice this on a circle centred around 0 and an even number of points, but when you want to transpose something in MATLAB always use `.'`, otherwise you may get some hard to diagnose issues! I have corrected this in my above code.

Doc links: [`ctranspose`/`'`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), [`transpose`/`.'`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html).

Comment: Wow...seems like the main issue was the identical points. It works like a charm after the rectification you suggested for the identical points. Thank you very much.

Comment: And thanks for the tips on the `'` transpose as well. Never knew that.

Comment: It was a head-scratcher, not obvious at all until I did a quick plot with 4 points and got a triangle! I've added documentation links for the transpose functions in case you're interested, they become important when you're playing with complex numbers!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the help once again.